# trying to redirect page with help of anchor tag in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

```
   <a href="LoginPage.js" class="login">Login</a>
```

So, user when he click on login button, he schould be redirected to loginpage which is inside of subfolder in src, imported file in app.js, and given above code in the localhost its showing like this http://localhost:3000/LoginPage.js    but not redirecting

Comment: You might be looking for a react router ?

Comment: Does redirecting to `http://localhost:3000/src/LoginPage.js`  work?

Comment: <div class="right-section">
                        <a href="LoginPage.js" class="login">Login</a>
                    </div>

Comment: not with help of react router. just redirection without react router

Answer (score 0):

1. install `react-router-dom` on your client using: `npm i --save react-router-dom`
2. Try this:

```
import { Link} from "react-router-dom";
..............................
...........................
   <button>
       <Link to="/login">
              Login
            </Link>
       </button>
............................
.....................
```

3. Make sure to have this in your main App.js component:

```
<Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
```